# How to close a notification in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

Having used [Avalonia.Controls.Notifications](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/api/untitled/avalonia-ui-framework-5/avalonia-ui-framework-12)  i'm using Show(INotification) method to show notification.
I can set a timer for notification to close it after timeout and can set an event handler for it to  handle onClick.
How can I close notification from my code by calling a method or any other way?

I tried to emulate click event but hadn't success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the instance of of `NotificationCard` that was created and call `Close()` method

```cs
// NotificationManager is the instance of WindowNotificationManager used to show the notification
var cards = NotificationManager.GetVisualChildren().FirstOrDefault() is ReversibleStackPanel panel ?
    panel.Children.OfType<NotificationCard>() : Array.Empty<NotificationCard>();

// Close the first notification if exists
cards.FirstOrDefault()?.Close();
```